# How to change Django Authentication View "PasswordResetView" to send resent link to mobile number and email?

Tags: python, django, django-views, twilio, django-authentication

I have a Custom User Model and Custom Backend for authenticating via both mobile number and email.

I want to give my users the ability to reset the password via both email and mobile number, i.e., on the PasswordResetView I want to have both options for resetting the password with the reset password link sent on the mobile number and on the email.

I have my Django project configured to send messages with Twilio.

My question is how to change the PasswordResetView to be able to do that.

Comment: I think you need to override `PasswordResetView` and write your own custom logic

Comment: Thank You @AchintyaRanjanChaudhary! It would be great if you could tell me how to override it, because I didn't find any documentation to help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to override the form_class of the view [PasswordResetView](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c609d5149c9295207cd7b2e8154e7b80a18d834a/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L212).

```
####### Your views.py ####### 

class PasswordResetViewOverride(auth_views.PasswordResetView):
    form_class = PasswordResetFormOverride
```

And then to achieve the authentication custom logic we need to override the save method of this default form_class that the PasswordResetView had, i.e., [PasswordResetForm](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c609d5149c9295207cd7b2e8154e7b80a18d834a/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L241). This class has a [save method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c609d5149c9295207cd7b2e8154e7b80a18d834a/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L283) we need to override that. Moreover, we can write its custom clean method and add any other field, in this case, a mobile number field.
After grabbing the user with the field of mobile number we can generate the token for them as shown [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c609d5149c9295207cd7b2e8154e7b80a18d834a/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L309). With this token, we will create a link and send to users' mobile number using any messaging client(like Twilio).

```
class PasswordResetFormOverride(PasswordResetForm):
    mobile_no = forms.CharField(
        label="Your Accounts' Mobile Number",
        max_length=10,
        widget=forms.NumberInput(),
        required=False,
    )
    def save(self, domain_override=None,
         subject_template_name='registration/password_reset_subject.txt',
         email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html',
         use_https=False, token_generator=default_token_generator,
         from_email=None, request=None, html_email_template_name=None,
         extra_email_context=None):
    mobile_no = self.cleaned_data.get("mobile_no", "")

    # All the previous stuff

    if mobile_no != "":
        # Send reset link to mobile logic
    
    # All the previous stuff
```